# Magento Ordered Items delete

Tags: magento, orders

i have to update an order, by deleting some items from order if it has multiple. and then have to update the Order.

Now i found the table: sales_flat_order_item where all the order items are.

$items = $order->getAllItems();

```
    foreach($items as $item){

        if($item->getParentItemId() == '' || $item->getParentItemId() == null){

            $product_id = $item->getProductId();
            if($product_id == $booking_product_id){             

                         // this item have to be deleted

            }

        }

    }
```

$order->save();

any suggestions ?

Comment: What is the overall aim, why are you trying to remove an item from an order?

Comment: This is client's requirement that he can cancel an item from his order, i am showing all order items separately.

Comment: i am trying some thing like $item->delete(). and this is now going fine. and then i update the order total price by deducting this item price that recently deleted from order.

Answer (score 3):

This way i got success.

```
    $base_grand_total = $order->getBaseGrandTotal();
    $base_subtotal = $order->getBaseSubtotal();
    $grand_total = $order->getGrandTotal();
    $subtotal = $order->getSubtotal();

    $base_subtotal_incl_tax = $order->getBaseSubtotalInclTax();
    $subtotal_incl_tax = $order->getSubtotalInclTax();
    $total_item_count = $order->getTotalItemCount();

    $items = $order->getAllItems(); 
    foreach($items as $item){       

        if($item->getParentItemId() == '' || $item->getParentItemId() == null){

            $product_id = $item->getProductId();
            if($product_id == $booking_product_id){             

            //remove item price from total price of order
            $item_price = $item->getPrice();
            $item->delete();

            $order->setBaseGrandTotal($base_grand_total-$item_price);
            $order->setBaseSubtotal($base_subtotal-$item_price);
                $order->setGrandTotal($grand_total-$item_price);
            $order->setSubtotal($subtotal-$item_price);

            $order->setBaseSubtotalInclTax($base_subtotal_incl_tax-$item_price);
            $order->setSubtotalInclTax($subtotal_incl_tax-$item_price);
            $order->setTotalItemCount($total_item_count-1);
            $order->save(); 
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: by using $item->delete(), i delete the item, and then by removing this item price from Order Price, i update the Order Totals. May be helpful for anyone.

Answer (score 0):

To Remove an item from the existing order.

Run below lines of code from the magento root as external code :

1. Save it as 'order_item_remove.php'
2. Run it as http://example.com/order_item_remove.php

Code Block as below:

```
<?php

require_once('app/Mage.php'); //Path to Magento
umask(0);
Mage::app();

try{
$_order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId('100000011'); // Order Increment Id
$items = $_order->getAllItems(); 

foreach ($items as $item){
    Mage::log('All items ' . print_r($item->getData(), true), null, 'items_data.log');
    $base_grand_total = $_order->getBaseGrandTotal();

    $base_subtotal = $_order->getBaseSubtotal();
    $base_tva = $_order->getBaseTaxAmount();

    $grand_total = $_order->getGrandTotal();

    $subtotal = $_order->getSubtotal();
    $tva = $_order->getTaxAmount();


    $base_subtotal_incl_tax = $_order->getBaseSubtotalInclTax();

    $subtotal_incl_tax = $_order->getSubtotalInclTax();

    $total_item_count = $_order->getTotalItemCount();
Mage::log('Items ' . $item->getSku(), null, 'items_data.log');


    if($item->getSku()=='SAMPLEKIT'){
        $item_price = $item->getPrice();
        $item_tva = $item->getTaxAmount();
        Mage::log('Item deleted ' . $item->getSku(), null, 'items_data.log');
        $item->delete();
        $_order->setBaseGrandTotal($base_grand_total-$item_price-$item_tva);

        $_order->setBaseSubtotal($base_subtotal-$item_price);

        $_order->setBaseTaxAmount($base_tva-$item_tva);

        $_order->setGrandTotal($grand_total-$item_price-$item_tva);

        $_order->setSubtotal($subtotal-$item_price);

        $_order->setTaxAmount($tva-$item_tva);


        $_order->setBaseSubtotalInclTax($base_subtotal_incl_tax-$item_price);

        $_order->setSubtotalInclTax($subtotal_incl_tax-$item_price);

        $_order->setTotalItemCount(count($items)-1);

        $_order->save(); 
    }

}
echo "success"; 
} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo "failed";
}
```